# Mysql can't start even after reboot

Tags: mysql, linux

hello my mysql no more work on my server so I hope to solve it soon.

When I type:
    service mysql start
I have the following message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

So I look at the first one and:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start-pre) since Mon 2017-04-17 00:08:42 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 24182 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-
file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Control: 24200 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             └─24200 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre



Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com systemd[1]: mysql.service holdoff time ...
Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Se...
Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Se...
Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[24200]: ls: cannot ...
Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[24200]: 2017-04-17T...
Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[24200]: 2017-04-17T...
Apr 17 00:08:42 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[24200]: 2017-04-17T...
```

Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

for :

```
journalctl -xn
```

I have:

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2017-04-16 23:42:18 UTC, end at Mon 2017-04-17 00:12:52 UTC
Apr 17 00:12:51 darphus.xen.prgmr.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Serve
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Apr 17 00:12:51 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[27976]: ls: cannot acc
Apr 17 00:12:51 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[27976]: 2017-04-17T00:
Apr 17 00:12:51 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[27976]: 2017-04-17T00:
Apr 17 00:12:51 darphus.xen.prgmr.com mysql-systemd-start[27976]: 2017-04-17T00:
Apr 17 00:12:52 darphus.xen.prgmr.com postfix/pickup[804]: warning: 1E20F25E72: 
Apr 17 00:12:52 darphus.xen.prgmr.com postfix/pickup[804]: 1E20F25E72: uid=0 fro
Apr 17 00:12:52 darphus.xen.prgmr.com postfix/proxymap[809]: warning: mysql:/etc
Apr 17 00:12:52 darphus.xen.prgmr.com postfix/cleanup[27709]: warning: proxy:mys
Apr 17 00:12:52 darphus.xen.prgmr.com postfix/cleanup[27709]: warning: 1E20F25E7
```

I did a purge of mysql-server mysql-client and mysql-common with autoclean and autoremove. I erased /var/lib/mysql
After I reinstalled and I still have the same problem as at the top of the message.

Comment: It looks like some of the information that is useful here has been truncated. As suggested by the first command, try using the `-l` flag to show the full log. Likewise the second log entry appears truncated - someone who recognises the first few characters of the error might be able to help, but the full lines would make the job much easier.